# How to call different types of grid/tilemap with (1+ words or sentence)?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

Grid - "A pattern or structure made from horizontal and vertical lines crossing each other to form squares".

Tilemap - "A two-dimensional grid made up of rectangular tiles of equal size".

Hexagonal "grid/map".
[image: Hexagon image catlikecoding.com] Source: catlikecoding.com

3D "grid/map".
[image: 3D grid]
Source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M7vC.jpg

Regular "grid/map".
[image: Regular grid.]
Source: https://godotengine.org/qa/17425/grid-navigation-like-minecraft-dont-want-unity3d-again-please

But it could also be anything that doesn't have a definite pattern to it. Like Navigation Mesh.
[image: NavMesh Unity]

It still consists of small parts/triangles that create whole "grid/map" area.

I guess that could be called just "map", but how do I define them afterwards? hex-map, 2D-grid-map, navigation-mesh-map? Does that sound ok to you (hex-map sounds good, but it's the usual case)?

Or the closest I could think - `square-map, hex-map, mesh-map`, but `map-system` - makes people think of a normal world map or something similar to it. So if there is a mathematical definition I would prefer that.

The reason I need this, is I am working on a program and 1 component will encompass behaviour/visual representation of all of those things depending on the settings. So I have to give that component a name that will describe all of these cases.

**How do I call all of these types of grids/hexagons/other types with (1 word or sentence) that defines them all?**

Comment: The one word solution is *decompositions*. *Tessellations* is okay as a general term but tends to be thought of as 2D decompositions. Depending on your viewpoint, you may want to use "discretizations". But that is more about sampling the properties of the surface at different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether 2-D, 3-D or more, this is called a

> [tiling or tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation).

Comment: Great answer! It will work for most people but won't work in my case because in 3D graphics Tessellation refers to a subdivision process or other techniques, frequently associated with shaders.

Comment: In case someone is interested what I mean - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation_(computer_graphics) .

Comment: Re: "won't work in my case" - then I have misunderstood what you are looking for. Can you elaborate on how what you'e looking for is different from a tiling or tessellation? Also, you may have more luck at a graphics site since you're asking for vocabulary specifically used for that community.

Comment: I will accept any answer that has most upvotes, I just stated that it doesn't work for me, but it for sure may work for someone else, I didn't mean that you haven't answered my question if that looked like it. Before last sentence in the question I have described why I need this, and I assumed that previous examples would convey the meaning of what I am looking for. Basically it's cells that can be any shape in any dimension structured in a repetitive or non-repetitive way, and those cells have position, size and shape. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Also, graphics community would kick me out because of a question like this :) They would say that the website is for questions that touch technical subjects and not Use of English :(

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ It's still not clear though what the concept is. You haven't described the actual concept, only given some pictures and some possible words for it (which may or may not be synonyms and so may be very misleading). Your first and second pictures look like 'tilings' to me. But the rest just asks if word 'x' is appropriate and all those words are sort of in the ballpark sort of but don't really mean any particular thing. What are you trying to do with this  component. Is it a word for all the -positions-? Or is it a word for all the things that can go at these positions?

Comment: All of those structures usually do the same work, they are used for pathfinding and define, for example, a game world, usually gamers are familiar with different types of these in different games. I have presented 4 examples that include different kind of situations, hex-grid when it's not square grid, most common square grid, also its 3D representation and not so visible to players a free movement grid which consists of polygons. These things are hard to describe easily, I can fit small descriptions of each of them in the question but the question already seemed too long.

Comment: In any case I have already answered my own question, so personally I no longer need an answer specific to my case. If you want to understand what I was looking for - you could read my answer and derive a meaning from it. But if other people find other answers or this question useful then I don't see a problem if answers don't have the specifics of the question. This was my best try at explaining what I was looking for - "component will encompass behaviour/visual representation of all of those things depending on the settings", it's true that you have to know a bit about them beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

I add the word *lattice* to other valid suggestions.

Cambridge has a restrictive definition of *lattice* that does not cover other wider uses:

> lattice = a structure made from strips of wood or other material that cross over each other with spaces between
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lattice)

Wider use is given  by:

> Lattice =
>
> 2 An interlaced structure or pattern resembling a lattice.
>
> "the lattice of branches above her"’
>
> 3 in Physics: A regular repeated three-dimensional arrangement of atoms, ions, or molecules in a metal or other crystalline solid
>
> [Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lattice)

The example of the branches shows that regularity is not a strict feature of a lattice. The mention of 3-dimensional leads naturally to the idea of a lattice in any number of dimensions. Hence it is easy to find mention of 2-D lattices such as you show.

For example, the title of an article:

> Near-zero thermal expansivity 2-D lattice structures: Performance in terms of mass and mechanical properties
>
> [Science Direct](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1359645410008694)

Comment: I like lattice, because it is in use for a similar structure in [musical tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(music)).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is about specific case of the question, I was looking for a word/combination of words which definition would include all of the different cases of tilemaps, be it 3D, 2D, have any shape, be some kind of structure which is divided into smaller chunks which can be represented visually using their shape.

Definition for `poly-` types describing shapes.

For 2D:

- Polygon.

For 3D:

- Polyhedron.

•• Polytope - it's definition is pretty vague, in mathematics it's used differently. But it's the closest thing I have found. [Wiki Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope).

The final touch would be to add something that defines structural behaviour/positioning of `polytopes` on a coordinate plane. Since we live in 3D(probably) and all applications usually use 3D to represent generic viewport of the world, we can use that information to think about `polytopes` in a 3-dimensional plane.

•• Cell - what can we use to describe a single entity in a 3D space? Probably a cell.

•• Structure - "The arrangement of and relations between the parts or elements of something complex".

We can come to conclusion that it could be: `polytope-cell-structure` or `cellular-polytope-structure`. Referring to cell might look like it's a biological structure, so not sure about that one, what do you think?

Could be: `polytope-entity-structure`, etc.

In the end I am not sure which one is the best to choose from `cell`, `entity`, etc. If you have any ideas, I would love to see them.

Node - doesn't really work because it's something connecting two lines/etc.

Section - more like it contains something.

Segment - works really well as a definition.

**FINAL - polytopes-segmented-structure or polytope-segments-structure or polytopial-segments-structure**

**Personal choice: polytopial-segments-structure**

***Alternatives:***

- Coordinate plane (definition is not quite right, but it if you think about looking at definition - it makes sense that it could be any type of structure on that plane).
- Cell divided plane.
- Cell divided dimension.
- Cell dimension.
- Coordinate dimension.

Comment: Why pluralize “segment(s)”??

Comment: @Jim because if I say `polytopial-segment-structure` for me it looks like it means - "that structure consists of 1 polytopial segment".

Comment: So you would also think a brick walkway only contains one brick. Or an apple pie only contains one apple?

Comment: @Jim that is conversational English, I can derive the meaning from use. But when you are reading a technical document those little intricacies matter a lot and can change the meaning altogether. For example, imagine that you had no prior knowledge that "apple pie" means a whole pie that has apples in it. In that case when reading "apple pie" would you actually think that it's a pie that contains apples or would you think that someone just placed 2 random words near each other? A good example is this virus song when a guy says those 2 words separately. Unless segments is a grammatic error here.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what a polytopial segments structure is either but I know using an s is wrong.   I probably would have gone with a polytopic cell structure.

Comment: @Jim true, I agree with you, for English use it's probably better to remove "s". The only reason I think it's better in my case is because it describes the technical meaning with more details, even if it's wrong statement itself. If someone reads it for their first time I don't want them to think that the structure consists of 1 polytopial segment. Polygon is a Polytope, and Polyhedron is a Polytope. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope